# Has there ever been an attempt to separate the facts and fiction in The Things They Carried?

Tags: the-things-they-carried, tim-o-brien

Tim O'Brien's novel of the Vietnam War, *The Things They Carried*, is usually labelled as fiction, even though aspects of it are based on settled history and the author's own experience serving a tour as an infantryman.

This blurring of fact and fiction is a key theme of the novel. One of the stories in the book makes a distinction between "story truth" and "happening truth" and argues that one is in no way superior to the other in terms of the actual "truth".

However, it would be interesting to know if O'Brien - or anyone else, perhaps a biographer - has ever attempted to split some of the fact from the fiction in the book?

Comment: O'Brien might argue that if you try to separate the fact from the fiction, you've shown that you haven't learned from the novel :) Regardless, this is a good question.

Comment: It might be worth comparing it to O'Brien's [*If I Die in a Combat Zone, Box Me Up and Ship Me Home*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_I_Die_in_a_Combat_Zone,_Box_Me_Up_and_Ship_Me_Home), or other O'Brien works about the war.